# Generated WSDL from a WCF service declares nullable, but it should be required

Tags: wcf, xsd, wsdl

I have a WCF service using a class, which is properly annotated as a DataContract. Within that data contract (which is a struct type) I have a **Prefix property** defined:

```
[DataContract(Name = "myIdentifier")]
[Serializable]
public struct MyIdentifierExtern {
    /// <summary>Gets or sets the identifier.</summary>
    /// <value>The identifier.</value>
    [DataMember(Name = "id", IsRequired = true, EmitDefaultValue = true, Order = 2)]
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "id", IsNullable = false, Order = 2)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    /// <summary>Gets or sets the prefix.</summary>
    /// <value>The prefix.</value>
    [DataMember(Name = "prefix", IsRequired = true, EmitDefaultValue = true, Order = 1)]
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "prefix", IsNullable = false, Order = 1)]
    [MaxLength(1)]
    [MinLength(1)]
    public string Prefix { get; set; }
...
```

However, the received WSDL (from accessing the service at it's configured URL with the "....svc?singleWsdl" query, returns:

```
<xs:complexType name="myIdentifier">
  <xs:annotation>
    <xs:appinfo>
      <IsValueType xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">true</IsValueType>
    </xs:appinfo>
  </xs:annotation>
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="prefix" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:element name="id" type="xs:int"/>
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

**Why is the prefix advertised as nillable?**

Comment: EmitDefaultValue will set that string property to null. Doesn't that kind of requires it should be nillable? probably the xsd generator is smart enough to recognize this?

Comment: @rene Thanks for this input. I tried, but however, it is still advertised as nillable.